# Please correct me on the following code in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

This is the following code in Odoo and does not work as I expected.

```python
 def _check_dates(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):    
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if rec.rdate and rec.gdate :
        start = date.strftime(str(rec.rdate), "%Y-%m-%d")
        end = date.strftime(str(rec.gdate), "%Y-%m-%d")
        if start >= end:
                return False
    return True

    _constraints = [
        (_check_dates, 'Error ! Received Date must be less or equal than given Date', ['rdate'])
        ]
```

Please correct me anyone. 
Thanks

Comment: What is the need of converting the dates to strftime? as later on you are comparing two dates?

Comment: yes it is actually comparing dates. what is the correct way for comparing dates ? I wanted to restrict and show a validation message

Comment: did you tried comparing directly as "if rec.rdate > rec.gdate" ? If you want to try, then check out the examples of "time.strptime"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the new Odoo 8 ORM API (no need to add anything to the `_constraints` list, which is now deprecated):

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('rdate', 'gdate')
def _check_dates(self):
    if self.rdate and self.gdate:
        start = fields.Date.from_string(self.rdate)
        end = fields.Date.from_string(self.gdate)
        if start > end:
            raise exceptions.ValidationError("Error! Received Date must be less or equal than given Date")
```

Note: I changed `start >= end` to `start > end` to make it consistent with your error message (since the previous code didn't accept equal dates).

---

Alternatively you can set it up as an SQL constraint, which has the benefit of working on a deeper, database level:

```
_sql_constraints = [
    (
        'rdate_gdate_check',
        'check(rdate <= gdate)',
        "Error! Received Date must be less or equal than given Date",
    ),
]
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much Ludwik

Comment: Ludwik Trammer, Please kindly can you help me out on this issue ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368499/what-is-wrong-with-following-code-in-python