# What is wrong with following code in Python?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I was trying to implement a constraint for a field
but instead of causing a constraint validation, it allows the record to get saved without showing any constraint message

```
def _check_contact_number(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
                if rec.contact_number:
                    size=len(str(rec.contact_number))
                    if size<10:
                       return False
            if not contact_number:
            return {}
            contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace('.','') 
#removes any '.' from the string
            contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace(' ','') 
#removes space from the string
            if not  contact_number.isdigit():
            return False
        return {}

    _constraints = [
        (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!', 
['contact_number']),
      ]
```

Kindly anyone correct me. Thank you very much

Comment: is it not raising warning?

Comment: Careful with the indentation. Check the return statements below your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This code has an ugly indents. Maybe this is the reason.
The right idents looks so:

```
def _check_contact_number(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if rec.contact_number:
            size=len(str(rec.contact_number))
            if size<10:
                return False
        if not contact_number:
            return {}
            contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace('.','') 
#removes any '.' from the string
            contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace(' ','') 
#removes space from the string
        if not  contact_number.isdigit():
            return False
        return {}
    _constraints = [
        (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!', ['contact_number']),
      ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming

```
_constraints = [
    (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!',
['contact_number']),
      ]
```

is correct syntax, and has proper indentation, this *should* be your code;

```
def _check_contact_number(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):

    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):

        contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace('.','') #removes any '.' from the string
        contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace(' ','') #removes space from the string
        contact_number = rec.contact_number.replace('-','') #removes any hyphens in the string

        if rec.contact_number:
            size=len(str(rec.contact_number))
            if size<10:
                return False

        if not contact_number:
            return {}

        if not  contact_number.isdigit():
            return False
        return {}

    _constraints = [
        (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!',
['contact_number']),
      ]
```

--If that does not work, we will need to see the entire `class` in order to correct this.

I do assume

```
_constraints = [
    (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!',
['contact_number']),
      ]
```

is incorrectly positioned as well, possibly causing the entire collapse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is more optimised code for constraint. make sure you restart the server and update the customised module in order to take effect of it.

```
def _check_contact_number(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    for rec in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if rec.contact_number:
            if len(str(rec.contact_number))<10:
               return False
            contact_number = str(rec.contact_number).replace('.','').replace(' ','')
            if not contact_number.isdigit():
                return False
        return True

_constraints = [
    (_check_contact_number, 'Enter valid phone number...!', ['contact_number']),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other answers sound reasonable, here is my attempt using the new Odoo ORM API:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('contact_number')
def _check_contact_number(self):
    contact_number = self.contact_number.replace('.','').replace(' ','')
    if len(contact_number) < 10:
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            "Phone number has to contain at least 10 digits!"
        )
    if not contact_number.isdigit():
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            "Phone number can only contain digits, spaces and dots!"
        )
```

[The current API for defining constrains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#openerp.api.constrains) is much nicer. You should really learn it. The old API you are using is deprecated and will eventually be removed.

Atul Arvind's tip about remembering to restart server and upgrade the particular module is also very important.